Can you drink alcohol on a public sidewalk in Houston?
Are you allowed to consume alcohol in the City of Houston on a public street? If not to the point of intoxication (BAC > 0.08)?
For the purposes of this question, let's say it's your alcohol not purchased at a bar or served by a TABC vendor.

FWIW, legal intoxication for purposes of driving is not the same as legal intoxication for purposes of being drunk in public.

@ohwilleke this is also my understanding, but that's why I'm here. I know this is a tremendously complex question though because everyone wants it to be illegal, and cops frequently just assume it is. Unless there is signs posted or it is assumed that it's legal (like at a public music pavilion or in an festival area.) I've asked cops before, and while I wouldn't trust their answers anyway they've always been very vague about this.

It depends where.
See Houston Code Sec. 3-3(b) and (c):

(b) It shall be unlawful for any person to be in possession of an open container in the central business district.
(c) It shall be unlawful for any person to engage in the public consumption of any alcoholic beverage in the central business district.

